# if-else inside for loop not working in python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, if-statement

I am writing a simple Python script with `if-else` condition in a for a loop by reading inputs line by line from a text file. Below is my script.
I should get the expected output. Please help!
My env.txt contains:

```
DEV01
DEV02
UAT01
UAT02
```

Here is the code:

```
with open("env.txt") as envnames:
    for eachenv in envnames:
        if eachenv=="DEV01" or "DEV02":
            eachenv="dev"
            print (eachenv)
        elif eachenv=="UAT01" or "UAT02":
            eachenv="uat"
            print(eachenv)
        else :
            print('')
```

Expected:

```
dev
dev
uat
uat
```

actual:

```
dev
dev
dev
dev
```

Comment: please add input file

Comment: @TalhaIsrar Unnecessary; problem is clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `if eachenv=="DEV01" or "DEV02"`.

you can not check like this. the result will be `True` if `eachenv=="DEV01"` otherwise the rusult will be `"DEV02"`, not `False`.
you should go like this:

```
if eachenv in ["DEV01", "DEV02"]:
```

also change `for eachenv in envnames:` to:

```
for eachenv in envnames.readlines():
```

Comment: This gives me empty output

Comment: I think all of the solutions here may give you an empty output, because `eachenv` is not `"DEV01"` or `"DEV01"`. I think it has an `\n` at the end. like this: `"DEV01\n"` @user1557960

Comment: change it  to `if eachenv.rstrip() in ["DEV01", "DEV02"]` then update me here.

Comment: Your welcome @user1557960. please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

```
 if eachenv=="DEV01" or "DEV02":
```

Means, if either of the following:

- `eachenv` is equal to `"DEV01"`
- `"DEV02"`

Well, what about `"DEV02"`? It exists, so that option of the condition is going to be "truthy", so your `if` will always pass.

This is not how chained conditions work.

You meant:

```
if eachenv=="DEV01" or eachenv=="DEV02":
```

Now it's, if either of the following:

- `eachenv` is equal to `"DEV01"`
- `eachenv` is equal to `"DEV02"`

Yay!

Answer (score 2):

In the line `if eachenv=="DEV01" or "DEV02":` the second condition is always true:

```
>>> if "DEV02":
...     print('hello')
... 
hello
```

This happens because the string `"DEV02"` is an object, therefore will be evaluated `True`.

@Lightness Races in Orbit gave the right way to write this if statement.